# File.WriteAllLines does not appear to be closing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a feature to a website that will send an outlook invite attachment to email.  Everything runs the first time perfectly, but after running it again, I get the following error:  "The process cannot access the file 'OutlookCalendar.ics' because it is being used by another process."  I have searched high and low for an answer to this but it appears that when I use file.WriteAllLines, it doesn't close the file?  See code below...

```
     //CREATE OUTLOOK ATTACHMENT.....................................................................................................
        //..............................................................................................................................
        string schLocation = "Kettle Cuisine TBD";
        string schSubject = visitor + " is visiting.";
        string schDescription = other;
        System.DateTime schBeginDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date + " " + time);
        System.DateTime schEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date + " 17:00");

        //PUTTING THE MEETING DETAILS INTO AN ARRAY OF STRING

        String[] contents = { "BEGIN:VCALENDAR",
                          "PRODID:-//Flo Inc.//FloSoft//EN",
                          "BEGIN:VEVENT",
                          "DTSTART:" + schBeginDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"), 
                          "DTEND:" + schEndDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"), 
                          "LOCATION:" + schLocation, 
                     "DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" + schDescription,
                          "SUMMARY:" + schSubject, "PRIORITY:3", 
                     "END:VEVENT", "END:VCALENDAR" };

        /*THE METHOD 'WriteAllLines' CREATES A FILE IN THE SPECIFIED PATH WITH 
       THE SPECIFIED NAME,WRITES THE ARRAY OF CONTENTS INTO THE FILE AND CLOSES THE
        FILE.SUPPOSE THE FILE ALREADY EXISTS IN THE SPECIFIED LOCATION,THE CONTENTS 
       IN THE FILE ARE OVERWRITTEN*/

        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Server.MapPath("OutlookCalendar.ics"), contents);

        //END CREATE OUTLOOK ATTACHMENT.....................................................................................................
        //..............................................................................................................................


        //Send out email
        Email.sendEmailOutlook(message, email, header);
```

In the email section I use this....
        //MAKE AN ATTACHMENT OUT OF THE .ICS FILE CREATED

```
        Attachment mailAttachment = new Attachment(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("OutlookCalendar.ics"));
        mail.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment);

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        //Set email message and subjet
        mail.Subject = header;
        mail.Body = message;

        smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines` explicitly closes the stream. You can check [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,8a8ede9e1ec4fece) or decompile assembly yourself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the problem isn't with `File.WriteAllLines`, but with `Attachment` - that implements `IDisposable`, but you're not disposing of it... so if that's got an open file handle on it, that would explain what you're seeing. You can just use:

```
var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("OutlookCalendar.ics");
using (Attachment mailAttachment = new Attachment(path))
{
    mail.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment);

    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    //Set email message and subjet
    mail.Subject = header;
    mail.Body = message;

    smtpClient.Send(mail);
}
```

However, it's not clear why you need to write to a file at all. It would be better to change your code to just create a `MemoryStream`. For example:

```
string text = string.Join("\r\n", contents);
byte[] encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
var stream = new MemoryStream(encoded);
using (var attachment = new Attachment(stream, "OutlookCalendar.ics"))
{
    ...
}
```

Now no files are involved at all, so there can't be any conflicts.

Comment: This is correct explanation, but having fixed file name in ASP.Net case will likely case intermittent issues when multiple requests are processed - [answer by Marko](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31571906/477420) addresses that by using memory stream.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: It reduces the race condition window very slightly, but it doesn't actually eliminate it. The OP is still writing to the same file in each case, and reading from that file. To *really* eliminate it, the OP should write to a memory stream *instead of a file entirely*. Will add something about that.

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses! Using MemoryStream has worked.

Comment: @Andy: But do you understand why you should *only* use a `MemoryStream`, and not a file at all? The answer you've accepted is still somewhat broken.

Comment: After reading your post again I do.  This way there is never a file opened and I will never see this issue.